# ThreeJS: how add PointLight to scene with PNG textures?

Tags: three.js

I have a scene with one mesh with PNG textures. I taken *PointLight* code from [ThreeJS example](https://threejs.org/examples/?q=shadow#webgl_shadowmap_pointlight) and added to my project:

```
 var intensity = 15;
 var pointLight = new THREE.PointLight( color, intensity, 20 );
 pointLight.castShadow = true;
 pointLight.shadow.camera.near = 1;
 pointLight.shadow.camera.far = 60;
 pointLight.shadow.bias = - 0.005;
```

But I not see light and shadows on my mesh:

[image: no light and shadows on mesh]

I created a [codepen](https://codepen.io/tolyanor/pen/QoYYyN?editors=1010) for reproduce this case

How I can resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were multiple problems with your pen:

- You have to tell the renderer to globally enable shadow maps like so:

  ```
  renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true
  ```
- You have to tell the extruded shape to receive shadows:

  ```
  mesh.receiveShadow = true;
  ```
- The extruded shaped used `MeshBasicMaterial` in your pen. This is an unlit material which means it does not react on lights. The codepen below now uses `MeshPhongMaterial`. You might want to consider to add an ambient or hemisphere light so all parts of your mesh are lit.

Codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vPPJxW?editors=1010

`three.js R102`